# Inert in Cathode when Electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry

Why Platinum, Gold, Carbon are inert? In electrolysis, it's not react in anode because anode is doing oxidizing, but how about cathode? Are they still inert?

Comment: Well, yes, they more or less are. What would you expect?

Comment: I mean, why they are not react, cahtode doing reduction, while Gold could does reduction the most, but why Gold doesnt resact?

Comment: Why would it? Metallic gold is already a reduced form.